# How can I iterate local files and perform an 'import photo' action in ipad Shortcut?

Tags: ipad, photos, shortcut

I have a bunch of photo currently sitting in my ipad, organized by date `01`, `02`... to `31`.

[image]

First of all I don't see any existing action in Shortcut in that allows me to iterate local file. Is it possible at all?

Then there is no action in Photo that let me to import a photo file.

Is there any solution to the above issues? I am happy to explore third party app to get around this problem.

Comment: Why are you accessing photos over a standard file interface? Just use the Photos app or Image Capture to handle imports. Both can see beyond the actual file structure.

Comment: 1. It is iPadOS so there is no ImageCapture 2. The source is not a camera and Photo on iPad does not recognize the SD card and hence the import tab does not show up.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't realised that was a view on iPadOS. In that case, I have no idea, sorry.